# Hide some Checkout Fields issue in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, field, checkout

I found a problem with hiding some of the checkout fields even after using :

```
// woocommerce checkout page  
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );
function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {

unset($fields['billing']['billing_company']);
unset($fields['billing']['billing_country']);
unset($fields['billing']['billing_state']);
return $fields;
}
```

I even tested with a plugin and the problem is still there its still showing the input on the front-end.

*After adding the code you can see that the input is still showing but it become shorter than the other Fields*:

[image: *after adding the code you can see that the input is still showing but it become shorter than the other Fields]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "*In specific cases you need to use the `woocommerce_default_address_fields` filter."* says [related official woocommerce documentation](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/) …

So you should try instead this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields', 'custom_checkout_fields' 20, 1 );
function custom_checkout_fields( $address_fields ) {

    unset($address_fields['company']);
    unset($address_fields['country']);
    unset($address_fields['state']);

    return $address_fields;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).*

It should works…

Comment: Thanks your answer was helpfull sir

Answer (score 2):

Solved the issue defining a priority and number of argument used in `add_action()` function:

```
// woocommerce checkout page  
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' ,'custom_override_checkout_fields',20,1 );
function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {

unset($fields['billing']['billing_company']);
unset($fields['billing']['billing_country']);
unset($fields['billing']['billing_state']);
return $fields;
}
```

Here is the Solution^^

Comment: Yours is also useful for others… Thanks